# How can I make a repeating wave?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

What is a good way to make a repeating wave without having to manually select every other face and drag it along an axis? I'm trying to make a very long wave and it would save me a lot of time on this project.

I'm trying to make something similar to the metal part of this image but a lot longer and more curved.

[image]

Comment: Make a single part and use an array modifier.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE.  In the US, we call this **corrugated** metal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a curve object and create the basic shape.

[image]

In the geometry section of the curve, give it some extrusion to get the height you want.

[image]

Use an array modifier to get as many copies as you need.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make a curve and use an array modifier[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can select 2 faces leaving one in between then pressing
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>numpad .</kbd>

[image]

E:This shortcut repeats the selection pattern.

Comment: Can you explain what that shortcut does?